# Replace on the basis of an value other values in a xml

Tags: python, xml

My XML structure is like the following:

```
<Root>
    <App>
        <Name>Monitoring1</Name>
        <Status>error</Status>
        <Date>2019-06-03</Date> 
        <Information>Error</Information>
    </App>
</Root>
```

I have a function "def writelog(a, b)", which creates a new entry on the App level, e. g. "Monitoring2".

So, when an item on the Name level already exists, I want to update the values.

Old:

```
<Root>
    <App>
        <Name>Monitoring1</Name>
        <Status>ERROR</Status>
        <Date>2019-06-03</Date> 
        <Information>Error</Information>
    </App>
</Root>
```

After calling the function, which will update Monitoring1:

```
<Root>
    <App>
        <Name>Monitoring1</Name>
        <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
        <Date>2019-06-03</Date> 
        <Information>Success</Information>
    </App>
</Root>
```

How can I achieve that?

Edit:

I tried something like:

```
for elem in root.getiterator():
    try:
        elem.text = elem.text.replace('FEATURE NAME', 'THIS WORKED')
        elem.text = elem.text.replace('FEATURE NUMBER', '12345')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

from [How to search and replace text in an XML file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868881/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-an-xml-file-using-python?rq=1)

or

```
tree.find('idinfo/timeperd/timeinfo/rngdates/begdate').text = '1/1/2011'
tree.find('idinfo/timeperd/timeinfo/rngdates/enddate').text = '1/1/2011'
```

from: [Find and Replace Values in XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python)

But I am completly lost at the moment

Comment: What have you tried so far for this

Comment: edited my thread.

Comment: Does the XML contain many apps? (`<App></App>`)? How can you tell if App exist already and replace its content?